# Cloudformation AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener arbitrary list of certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to write a CloudFormation template that will support multiple environments, and each env can have 2 or 3 certificates that should be attached to the load balancer listener.

However, since Cloudformation doesnt accept a simple list of certificate arns ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-listener-certificates.html)), I'm struggling to figure out how to pass in a list of objects using parameters. It seems that:

1. Each parameter MUST have a type
2. "List" is not an acceptable type, it must be a list "of something"
3. Cloudformation does not have a "foreach" to create a "cert object" from each certificate arn on-the-fly.

I came across this example template ([link](https://github.com/stelligent/application-loadbalancer-multi-cert/blob/master/AutoScalingMultiAzWithNotificationsAndMultiCerts.template)), but here the problem is solved by using two explicit certificates - I need to be able to dynamically input an arbitrary list of certificates

For ref, I need to be able to inject something like this (pseudocode):

`Certificates:
 - Certificate: Arn1
 - Certificate: Arn2
 - Certificate: Arn_n`

Where Arn1, Arn2, Arn_n comes from a "list-type" Parameter.

So I guess the question is: Is there any "foreach" or anything else in Cloudformation that could help me generate one "object" per item in a parameter list, or any way to pass in "rich" parameter objects?

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormation allows you to use a `CommaDelimitedList` as a parameter type. You can then supply this in the form of a comma-separated list:

> arn1,arn2,arn3

The list is arbitrary. You can then supply this into your listener's `Certificates` property directly:

```
"Certificates" : { "Ref" : "MyListParam" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question to make it a bit more clear what the limitations are.

Comment: I see the issue. So this solution won't work directly. CloudFormation doesn't have a `foreach` type of structure. You may be able to do what you want with conditionals.

Comment: Thanks! We apply cloudformation using Ansible, so I ended up with a bit of Jinja2 magic instead. Just surprised its implemented like this, when it results in limitations.